# Reset Datagridview SelectionBackColor

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my code I have need to turn the SelectionBackColor to red to notify the user of something. When that has been rectified I wish to set it again back to its default (Blue with white text). I use color.empty but this seams to not work correctly. It resets the color BUT subsequent repeat changes to SelectionBackColor are not implemented.

I use this to change it `Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red`

and this to reset `Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty`

But as I said subsequent attempts to change the color fails, even when done on the same cell that worked the first time. As I said above it's as if Im not resenting correctly. OR is it that this can only be changed once? Unlikely though

EDIT:
I tried to change the color to green instead of empty and that has worked correctly, several times over changing the color from red to green as expected. So it is definitely an issue with the color.empty (trying to reset it to default) and not code or logic anywhere else.
Thanks for any thoughts you may have

Edit2: Is there a way to capture the default style and then recall it? So instead changing to green I change to the saved default style?

Comment: Do you have other events on your DataGridView1 that change the `SelectionBackColor` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer I found by trial and error to reset the SelectionBackColor is to first capture it and then use it when resetting.

```
Dim GridBackcolor As Object
  GridBackcolor = Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor
'set another color
 Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red
'reset
  Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = GridBackcolor
```

in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the solution was to set:

```
.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor
```

AND

```
.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor
```

switch to custom colors and back worked allready....
BUT
the 2. switch dosent changed the selection color. also not the background and forecolor...

perhaps the datagridview "think" one of them (selectionforecolor, selectionbackcolor, background, forecolor) could be the "same" color and has a problem with switching them ... ?

cheers :-)